# "KeyError: Node not in graph" when using pygraphviz_layout even though node is in networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx, pygraphviz

I have a DataFrame `network_df` consisting of an edge list

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(network_df,source='Parent Node',target= 'Child Node',create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

I'm using `pygraphviz_layout` to calculate the position of each node in `G`

```
  pos = pygraphviz_layout(G,prog="dot", args='-Gnodesep=10-Goverlap=false')
```

But this raises the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\..\Python37\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1615, in __new__
  nh = gv.agnode(graph.handle, n.encode(graph.encoding), _Action.find)
  KeyError: 'agnode: no key'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\Python37\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_agraph.py", 
  line 293, in pygraphviz_layout
  node = pygraphviz.Node(A, n)
  File "C:\...\Python37\lib\site- 
  packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1617, in __new__
    raise KeyError("Node %s not in graph." % n)

  KeyError: "Node ('', '', 'A /// Standard', 'Event A') not in graph."
```

But when I do

```
key = ('', '', 'A /// Standard', 'Event A')
print(key in G.nodes())
```

This prints `True` meaning that the node is indeed in the Graph, what can I be doing wrong here?

Also, if I use some other function to calculate the position, it works

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

What is wrong here? `pygraphviz_layout` has worked without any problems before for other datasets.

Comment: Have you tried converting your nodes to integers, i.e. [`convert_node_labels_to_integers`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers)?

Comment: I have not, is it possible to revert the labels? I will merge the resulting positions with the initial dataframe

Comment: You can store the original labels in an attribute and revert it afterwards with [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html#networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes)

Comment: So if I do

G = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G,label_attribute='old_label')

what would be the correct way to revert it? How do I pass the 'old_label' to relabel_nodes?

Comment: First try if it fixes your error, then I would create an answer explaining, how you can change the labels back and forth (including updating the `pos` variable ;))

Comment: Thanks, will try it first.

Comment: Yes, it fixed the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import networkx as nx

# an example graph with string (names) as nodes
g = nx.les_miserables_graph()


labels_to_int = {}
int_to_labels = {}
for i, label in enumerate(g):
    labels_to_int[label] = i
    int_to_labels[i] = label

# update labels to ints with
nx.relabel_nodes(g, labels_to_int, copy=False)
print(g.nodes)
# Tested only with the following since I have pygraphviz not installed 
pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(g)
# pos = pygraphviz_layout(G,prog="dot", args='-Gnodesep=10-Goverlap=false')

# changes back to original labels
nx.relabel_nodes(g, int_to_labels, copy=False)

label_pos = {label: pos[labels_to_int[label]] for label in g}
print(label_pos)
# {'Napoleon': array([0.73407672, 0.66096404]), 'Myriel': array([0.67744174, 0.53499379]), ....
print(g.nodes)
# ['Napoleon', 'Myriel', ...
```

### Background

The reason for you error is probably that `pygraphviz` cannot work with arbitrary (hashable) nodes unlike `networkx`. Therefore, above code simply cast the node labels to `int` before calling the layout and revert the changes in the nodes and the `pos` dict.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using arbitrary hashable nodes doesn't work with the `pygraphviz` backend, but it does with `pydot`:

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

g = ...
pos = graphviz_layout(g, "dot")
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=pos)
```

The key point here is importing `graphviz_layout` from `networkx.drawing.nx_pydot` and not `networkx.drawing.nx_agraph` or elsewhere.